# How to retrieve sub query values when using top 1

Tags: sql, subquery, pervasive-sql

I want to join two tables in a query extracting some information from each, but the second table requires a TOP 1:

This gets my list of people

```
SELECT [Clock no], [Card id], [Current pay cat], [Pay category] 
FROM Employees EMP 
WHERE [Clocked in flag] = 'Y'
```

Now for each of the people in that table I want to join to this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Start time], Dated FROM [Work records] WR 
WHERE WR.[Clock no] = XXXXXXXXX <- Clock no from first query
AND WR.Dated <= '2013-01-07' AND WR.[Open flag] = 'Y' 
ORDER BY WR.[Dated] DESC, WR.[Start time] DESC
```

What I have so far is something like this, but I can't seem to get it to work as soon as I add the ORDER By clause:

```
SELECT EMP.[Clock no], [Card id], [Current pay cat], [Pay category], WRTOP.[Start time], WRTOP.[Dated]
FROM Employees EMP 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT TOP 1 [Clock no], [Start time], Dated FROM [Work records] WR 
WHERE WR.Dated <= '2013-01-07' AND WR.[Open flag] = 'Y' 
ORDER BY WR.[Dated] DESC, WR.[Start time] DESC
) WRTOP 
ON (EMP.[Clock no] = WRTOP.[Clock no])
WHERE EMP.[Clocked in flag] = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subquery returns one row, not necessarily for the right `Clock no`.  Only looking at the right `Clock no` requires a relation between the subquery and an outer table.   That's not allowed in `join`.

One way around that is a subquery in the `on` condition, like:

```
SELECT  EMP.[Clock no]
,       EMP.[Card id] 
,       EMP.[Current pay cat]
,       EMP.[Pay category]
,       WR.[Start time]
,       WR.[Dated]
FROM    Employees EMP 
JOIN    [Work records] WR 
ON      WR.[Open flag] = 'Y' 
        AND WR.[Clock no] = EMP.[Clock no]
        AND WR.Dated =
        (
        SELECT  max(Dated)
        FROM    [Work records] WR2
        WHERE   WR2.[Open flag] = 'Y'
                AND WR2.[Clock no] = EMP.[Clock no]
                AND WR2.Dated <= '2013-01-07'
        )
        AND WR.[Start time] =
        (
        SELECT  max([Start time])
        FROM    [Work records] WR3
        WHERE   WR3.[Open flag] = 'Y'
                AND WR3.[Clock no] = EMP.[Clock no]
                AND WR3.Dated = 
                (
                SELECT  max(Dated)
                FROM    [Work records] WR4
                WHERE   WR4.[Open flag] = 'Y'
                        AND WR4.[Clock no] = EMP.[Clock no]
                        AND WR4.Dated <= '2013-01-07'
                )
        )
WHERE EMP.[Clocked in flag] = 'Y'
```

Comment: I am using Pervasive SQL so I don't think `APPLY` is a valid keyword

Comment: Thanks - this *nearly* works, (I changed to use the `Transaction no` primary key) but I still need to get `TOP 1` on the subquery ordered by `dated` then `start time` (there may be more than one record on a given day) and as soon as I add ORDER BY it fails

Comment: Better stay with `max(Dated)` then, that would at least give you the one row with the highest `Dated`.

Comment: As I said that won't work because there could be more than one item on the same day

Comment: Does it work with the `top` clause, as edited in the answer?  (Pervasive seems like an unusual SQL language, can't find much documentation in Google.)

Comment: No it doesn't like the `ORDER BY` part if I remove that it executes but the results are wrong. I appreciate your help on this. For reference here is a [link to the Pervasive Docs](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=welcome/libwelcome.html)

Comment: You could try a double condition, one for the latest `Dated` and one for the latest `Start time` for the latest `Dated`.  Updated in answer.

Comment: Yes that worked thanks for the time you spent on this. This is now in the realms of 'too complex to make it worthwhile now though'